# s:submit no funciona al migrar struts2 version 2.2.1.1 a 2.3.16.1

Tags: java, jboss, struts, struts2

Mi problema es que se migro un aplicativo hecho en struts2 2.2.1.1 en Jboss5 a una versión de struts2 2.3.16.1 y con jboss6, al realizar las configuraciones necesarias, ,logre que el aplicativo funcionara casi en su totalidad, mi único de talle fue que la  etiqueta  ya no trabaja, no hace ninguna acción. Investigue un poco y encontre que había que agregar constantes al struts.xml para esta nueva versión que efectivamente tenía ese error, y así lo hice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
<"DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.serve.static" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />

<package name="REGEVAL" extends="struts-default">

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="sessionCheckInterceptor" class="mx.gob.coneval.regeval.common.SessionCheckInterceptor" />

        <interceptor-stack name="regevalStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="sessionCheckInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="profiling"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">back,cancel,browse,execute,drop,fetch</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
```

Pero aún así no funciona la etiqueta.  Mi web esta de esta forma

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"> 
 <context-param>
 <param-name>org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactory.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener</listener-class>
  </listener> 

  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
<filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
<session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>

</web-app>
```

y mis dos s:submit son

```
<s:submit id="btnDetailBoxEdit" name="btnSubmitEditCentro" action="formaAcadUpdateGrado" key="ui.common.btn.save" cssStyle="display: none" />
<s:submit id="btnDetailBoxAdd"  name="btnSubmitAddCentro"  action="formaAcadSave"        key="ui.common.btn.add"  cssStyle="display: none" />
```

Que creen que pueda ser?? me faltará alguna configuración?,

Comment: ¿Imagino que tus `<s:submit>` se encuentran dentro de un `<s:form>`, cierto?

Comment: efectivamente estan dentro de un <s:form>

Comment: no sirve de nada que nos pongas los `<s:submit>` si no pones el `<s:form>`